# applescript: automatically delete files in folder if file with same name is present

Tags: applescript

I have a folder in my google drive where `.docx` files are shared to continue editing them with Google docs. Google docs now creates documents with the extension `.gdoc` so that I now have every document twice, once called `"test.docx"` and `"test.docx.gdoc"`. Now I want to automatically delete the `.docx` file as soon as the `.docx.gdoc` file with the same name is present.

I tried this one, but it does not delete the .docx files:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    tell application "Finder"
    set docxFiles to every file of this_folder whose name extension is "docx"
    repeat with aFile in docxFiles
        set baseName to text 1 thru -6 of (get name of aFile)
        set gdocFile to baseName & ".docx.gdoc"
        if exists gdocFile then delete aFile
    end repeat
end tell
end adding folder items to
```

In my testing I'm relatively sure that everything works up to the line

```
set gdocFile to baseName & ".docx.gdoc
```

The line that doesn't do anything seems to be

```
if exists gdocFile then delete aFile
```

Any Idea?

Comment: I think you are having your script do more work that it has to. You are already capturing which files were just received, just loop through those files and check for the existence of the other file.

Comment: As for "it doesn't work", what doesn't work about it? Can you give more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot work because you're composing the `.docx.gdoc` filename without the full path

Try this

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    tell application "Finder"
        set docxFiles to every file of this_folder whose name extension is "docx"
        repeat with aFile in docxFiles
            set gdocFile to (aFile as text) & ".gdoc"
            if exists file gdocFile then delete aFile
        end repeat
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

I would do it the other way round. Iterate thru the `.docx.gdoc` files and delete the corresponding `docx` files.

Comment: Vadian, you made my day! Thanks so much!